# Generate a new integer_sequence by removing duplicates

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, c++20

I implemented a compile time check to check if something is sorted using the code given below:

```c++
template<typename IntegerSequence>
struct is_sorted {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename Integer, Integer Head, Integer Next, Integer... Tail>
struct is_sorted<std::integer_sequence<Integer, Head, Next, Tail...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = Head <= Next && is_sorted<std::integer_sequence<Integer, Next, Tail...>>::value;
};
```

The above code works. I am planning to create a two additional meta function with these sorted checks which would generate new sequence without duplicates

```c++
using in_seq = std::integer_sequence<int, 1,2,3,4>;

using mod_seq = is_sorted<in_seq>::value ? remove_duplicates<in_seq>::uniq_seq : in_seq;
// Examples
// in_seq = 1,2,3,4 -> mod_seq = 1,2,3,4
// in_seq = 1,2,2,3,4 -> mod_seq = 1,2,3,4
```

how to remove duplicates from integer sequence using templates at compile time.
Also is it possible to remove duplicates while we are performing the sort check, in this case I am fine if we stop removing duplicates as soon as templates detect that sequence is not sorted.

```
// partial sort example 4,4,4,5,5,3,2,2,1 -> 4,5,3,2,2,1 (not sure if this is possible, but just curious)
```

I am unsure how to go by generating new `std::integer_sequence` on the fly.

Comment: You've tagged this with c++20. Are you aware that algorithms like `sort` etc are now `constexpr`? You can do compile-time programming of this nature without any template meta-programming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also is it possible to remove duplicates while we are performing the sort check, in this case I am fine if we stop removing duplicates as soon as templates detect that sequence is not sorted.

Yes, it's possible.

Maybe can be done a little simpler, but... using and abusing template specialization...

Given an helper class as the following

```
// csardh: check sort and remove duplicates helper
template <typename T, typename>
struct csardh
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0, T v1, T ... vs>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0, v1, vs...>>
   : public std::conditional_t<
        (v0 < v1),
        csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0>,
               std::integer_sequence<T, v1, vs...>>,
        csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0, v1, vs...>, void>>
 { };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0, T ... vs>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0, v0, vs...>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
                   std::integer_sequence<T, v0, vs...>>
 { };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0>, void>
 { };
```

the main class become

```
// csard: check sort and remove duplicates
template <typename>
struct csard;

template <typename T, T... vals>
struct csard<std::integer_sequence<T, vals...>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T>,
                   std::integer_sequence<T, vals...>>
 { };
```

A `using` can be useful to simplify the use

```
template <typename T>
using csard_t = typename csard<T>::type;
```

The following is a full compiling example (C++14 is enough)

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// csardh: check sort and remove duplicates helper
template <typename T, typename>
struct csardh
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0, T v1, T ... vs>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0, v1, vs...>>
   : public std::conditional_t<
        (v0 < v1),
        csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0>,
               std::integer_sequence<T, v1, vs...>>,
        csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0, v1, vs...>, void>>
 { };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0, T ... vs>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0, v0, vs...>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
                   std::integer_sequence<T, v0, vs...>>
 { };

template <typename T, T ... ordered, T v0>
struct csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered...>,
              std::integer_sequence<T, v0>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T, ordered..., v0>, void>
 { };

// csard: check sort and remove duplicates
template <typename>
struct csard;

template <typename T, T... vals>
struct csard<std::integer_sequence<T, vals...>>
   : public csardh<std::integer_sequence<T>,
                   std::integer_sequence<T, vals...>>
 { };

template <typename T>
using csard_t = typename csard<T>::type;

int main()
 {
   using T0 = std::integer_sequence<int,4,4,4,5,5,3,2,2,1>;
   using T1 = csard_t<T0>;
   using T2 = std::integer_sequence<int,4,5,3,2,2,1>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, "!" );

   using U0 = std::integer_sequence<int,1,2,3,4>;
   using U1 = csard_t<U0>;
   using U2 = U0;

   static_assert( std::is_same<U1, U2>::value, "!" );

   using V0 = std::integer_sequence<int,1,2,2,3,4>;
   using V1 = csard_t<V0>;
   using V2 = U2;

   static_assert( std::is_same<V1, V2>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: thanks @max66, I definitely like the use of conditional, must say lot to learn with respect to parameter packing. Thanks for this approach

Answer (score 6):

Since all std algorithm are now `constexpr` in C++20, we can use it to do *compile-time programming* in the nature way (just like [@cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) say):

```
template <typename T, T... Ints>
constexpr auto unique_until_nonsorted(std::integer_sequence<T, Ints...>) {
  // constexpr structured bindings are not allow :(
  constexpr auto pair = [] {
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Ints)> arr{Ints...};
    // get last iterator of unique
    auto sorted_end = std::is_sorted_until(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    // unique until last iterator
    auto unique_end = std::unique(arr.begin(), sorted_end);
    // copy nonsorted elements to last iterator
    auto copy_end = std::copy(sorted_end, arr.end(), unique_end);
    // get final arr size
    auto size = std::distance(arr.begin(), copy_end);
    return std::pair{arr, size};
  }();
  constexpr auto arr  = pair.first;
  constexpr auto size = pair.second;
  // using template lambda to expand pack
  return [&arr]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::integer_sequence<T, arr[Is]...>{};
  }(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}
```

[Works for GCC and Clang.](https://godbolt.org/z/aj33Pe)

```
template <typename X, X... Xs, typename Y, Y... Ys>
constexpr bool operator==(std::integer_sequence<X, Xs...>,
                          std::integer_sequence<Y, Ys...>) noexcept {
  return ((Xs == Ys) && ...);
}

static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<4,4,4,5,5,3,2,2,1>{}) ==
                                     std::index_sequence<4,5,3,2,2,1>{});
static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>{}) == 
                                     std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>{});
static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<1,2,2,3,4>{}) == 
                                     std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>{});
static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<2,2,2,2,4,1,1>{}) == 
                                     std::index_sequence<2,4,1,1>{});
static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<1,1,1,2,3,2,2>{}) == 
                                     std::index_sequence<1,2,3,2,2>{});
// corner case
static_assert(unique_until_nonsorted(std::index_sequence<>{}) == 
                                     std::index_sequence<>{});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this with [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html). There, the "integer sequence" concept is a little different, we deal with lists of types. `mp_list_c<int, 1, 2>` is the type `mp_list<mp_int<1>, mp_int<2>>`. This makes a lot of metaprogramming much easier. Everything here is a one-liner.

First, `is_sorted`. One algorithm that's currently missing from Mp11 (shocker) is the ability to do `zip_with` - that is, take a list and zip that list with itself offset by one:

```
template <typename L, template <typename...> class P>
using zip_with = mp_transform<P, mp_pop_back<L>, mp_pop_front<L>>;
```

Now, `is_sorted` is basically: take that list and check if every pair has the first element less than the second:

```
template <typename L>
using is_sorted = mp_rename<zip_with<L, mp_less>, mp_all>;
```

Removing duplicates? That's something there's already an algorithm for: `mp_unique`.

Putting it altogether:

```
using mod_seq = mp_if_c<is_sorted<L>::value, mp_unique<L>, L>;
```

There's no conditional operator for types, you need something like `mp_if` (or `std::conditional_t`).

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use Boost. Though I definitely I like the mod_seq derivation using is_sorted.

Comment: @IBRIT In retrospect, `mp_unique` just removes all duplicates, it doesn't require sorted-ness. I wasn't sure if that was part of the problem or not. Mp11 is also a standalone library, so you should use it :-)

Comment: yeah I just started looking at Mp11, will definitely keep in mind. thanks for providing an alternative solution.